# UWP how to make a focusable Image?

Tags: image, xaml, canvas, uwp, controls

I'm trying to create a Image which is focusable in order to show moving or resize thumb.I know that Image tag is not a control so it is not focusable which explained in this [Image Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image). But I need to make some event to allow the image to know whether is being Focus in order to change the visibility of those control thumbs.Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
My control in Canvas is following.

```
         <Canvas x:Name="test">
            <Grid x:Name="grdTextbox" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300" Height="200" Width="200" ManipulationMode="None">
                <Thumb x:Name="ThumbMove" Background="Transparent" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" DragDelta="ThumbMove_DragDelta" PointerEntered="ThumbMove_PointerEntered" PointerExited="ThumbMove_PointerExited" Margin="5" Canvas.ZIndex="1"  />
                <Thumb x:Name="ThumbBottomRight" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DragDelta="ThumbBottomRight_DragDelta" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PointerEntered="ThumbSizeNorthwestSoutheast_PointerEntered" PointerExited="ThumbMove_PointerExited"/>
                <Thumb x:Name="ThumbBottomLeft" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black"  Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DragDelta="ThumbBottomLeft_DragDelta" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PointerEntered="ThumbSizeNortheastSouthwest_PointerEntered" PointerExited="ThumbMove_PointerExited"/>
                <Thumb x:Name="ThumbTopRight" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black"  Height="20" Width="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" DragDelta="ThumbTopRight_DragDelta" VerticalAlignment="Top" PointerExited="ThumbMove_PointerExited" PointerEntered="ThumbSizeNortheastSouthwest_PointerEntered"/>
                <Thumb x:Name="ThumbTopLeft" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black"  Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DragDelta="ThumbTopLeft_DragDelta"  VerticalAlignment="Top" PointerExited="ThumbMove_PointerExited" PointerEntered="ThumbSizeNorthwestSoutheast_PointerEntered"/>
                <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="Assets/Square150x150Logo.png" Margin="2" Stretch="Uniform" PointerEntered="ThumbMove_PointerEntered" PointerExited="ThumbMove_PointerExited"  Tapped="Image_Tapped"/>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very nice description of enabling keyboard accessibility including focus is in the [UWP documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/accessibility/keyboard-accessibility#keyboard-alternatives-to-pointer-actions-and-events-for-specific-control-elements).

As it states:

> In cases where an element that you want to use in the UI cannot have focus, you could create your own custom control. You must set the IsTabStop property to true to enable focus and you must provide a visual indication of the focused state by creating a visual state that decorates the UI with a focus indicator.

So what you could do is to wrap the `Image` in a [custom control](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-Custom-Controls-a031a7ea) which handles the focus.

The documentation however also says that:

> It is often easier to use control composition so that the support for
>   tab stops, focus, and Microsoft UI Automation peers and patterns are
>   handled by the control within which you choose to compose your
>   content.

So if you want to aim for the solution with better pre-implemented support, you could just wrap your `Image` in an existing control like `Button`:

```
<Button>
 <Image />
</Button>
```

The advantage is that the behavior of focus is already implemented fully out of the box. The disadvantage is that the `Button` does much more than just focusing, of course, and you will probably have to modify the default style to remove the styling you don't need.

Comment: Thank you So much !!!! I keep searching around the internet but I only can find all about WPF which using the Focusable=True method. Thank you for your helping!